# Is Equivalence relation an abstraction of a usual equality?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I'm studying group theory and I came across many equivalence relations.The one which fascinated me the most was isomorphic relation.

Now my doubt is,is equivalence relation an abstraction of our usual sense of equality?Like see even in case of isomorphism intuitively there is some sense of equality or similarlity right?

Comment: Equivalence is a generalization of equality. They both have the properties of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.

Comment: An isomorphism is literally an abstraction of equality, indeed. As per why equality is often the trivial isomorphism.